# How to set CURVES for OpenGov Tracks?

Tags: opengov

I need to customise the tracks for my OpenGov implementation. How should I do that?
I mean what are the things I would need to consider and how to make a decision on that?

Curve default code:

```
const APP_ROOT: Curve = Curve::make_reciprocal(4, 14, percent(80), percent(50), percent(100));
const SUP_ROOT: Curve = Curve::make_linear(14, 14, permill(5), percent(25));
```